# Interval between checkpoints in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, checkpoint

How can I specify the interval between 2 consecutive checkpoints in tensorflow? There are no options in `tf.train.Saver` to specify that. Every time, I run the model with a different number of global steps, I get a new interval between checkpoints

Answer (score 3):

The [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) is a "passive" utility for writing checkpoints, and it only writes a checkpoint when some other code calls its [`.save()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver#save) method. Therefore, the rate at which checkpoints are written depends on what framework you are using to train your model:

- If you are using the low-level TensorFlow API (`tf.Session`) and writing your own training loop, you can simply insert calls to `Saver.save()` in your own code. A common approach is to do this based on the iteration count:

  ```
  for i in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
    sess.run(train_op)
    # ...
    if i % 1000 == 0:
      saver.save(sess, ...)  # Write a checkpoint every 1000 steps.
  ```
- If you are using [`tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredTrainingSession), which writes checkpoints for you, you can specify a checkpoint interval (in seconds) in the constructor. By default it saves a checkpoint every 10 minutes. To change this to every minute, you would do:

  ```
  with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(..., save_checkpoint_secs=60):
    # ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! 
This fixed my problem:
tf.contrib.slim.learning.train(
        train_op,
        checkpoint_dir,
        log_every_n_steps=args.log_every_n_steps,
        graph=g,
        global_step=model.global_step,
        number_of_steps=args.number_of_steps,
        init_fn=model.init_fn,
        save_summaries_secs=300,
        save_interval_secs=300,
        saver=saver)