# Saving tensorflow-slim model using steps intervals instead of time interval (seconds)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I am using [object detection in tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) api. In my previous work I used to check the current step and save my model every *n* steps, something like the approach mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver).

In this case though the authors use [TensorFlow-Slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim) to perform the training. So, they use a `tf.train.Saver` which is passed to the actual function which performs the training: `slim.learning.train()`. While this function has some parameters regarding the interval for writing down the training model using the parameter [`save_interval_secs`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py#L551) it is time dependent and not step dependent.

So, since `tf.train.Saver` is a "passive" utility as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739036/3584765) and just saves a model with the provided parameters, meaning is ignorant of any time or step notions, and also in object detection code the control is passed in *TensorFlow-Slim*, by passing the saver as a parameter, in this case how can I achieve to save my model step-ward (every *n steps* instead of every *x seconds*)?

The only solution is to dig into slim code and edit it (with all risks coming from this)? Or is there another option I am not familiar with?

P.S.1
I found out there is a astonishingly similar question about this option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48465648/3584765) but unfortunately it did not have any answers. So, since my problem persists I will leave this question intact to raise some interest in the issue.

P.S.2
Looking into `slim.learning` code I found out that in `train()` after passing the parameters it just passes the control over to `supervisor.Supervisor` which refers to [`tf.train.Supervisor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor) which is a bit odd since this class is considered deprecated. The use of `supervisor` is also mentioned in the docstrings of `slim.learning`.